# Python Pandas - Pivot table outputs floats unexpectedly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that contains integers, however when I pivot it, it creates floats and I cannot work out why:

My Dataframe (dfDis) looks like this:

```
    Year    Type                                                Total
0   2006    A talk or presentation                                 34
1   2006    A magazine, newsletter or online publication           33
2   2006    A formal working group, expert panel or dialogue        2
3   2006    Scientific meeting (conference/symposium etc.)         10
4   2006    A press release, press conference or response ...       6
....
```

My pivot code is:

```
dfDisB = pd.pivot_table(dfDis, index=['Year'], columns = ['Type'],fill_value=0)
```

And for some reason dfDisB ends up like this (sorry for formatting, I hope you get the gist):

```
    Total
Type    A broadcast e.g. TV/radio/film/podcast (other than news/press)  A formal working group, expert panel or dialogue    A magazine, newsletter or online publication    A press release, press conference or response to a media enquiry/interview  A talk or presentation  Engagement focused website, blog or social media channel    Participation in an activity, workshop or similar   Participation in an open day or visit at my research institution    Scientific meeting (conference/symposium etc.)
Year                                    
2006    1.000000    1.571429    6.125000    2.000000    3.235294    1.000000    4.222222    1.000000    5.500000
2007    0.000000    3.666667    24.500000   11.500000   32.250000   1.000000    5.250000    2.500000    28.000000
2008    0.000000    2.500000    21.333333   13.000000   38.230769   1.000000    7.909091    1.000000    37.000000
```

I am confused as I pivot some other data earlier on in my report, but I dont have the problem.

Any suggestions? I have exported dfDis to a csv to check there were no floats in there and there are not, it is just whole numbers.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand this behaviour, note:

1. The default aggregation method for `pd.pivot_table` is 'mean'.
2. The mean of 3 integers is often not an integer.
3. If any of the values in the pivot table are `float` [including `NaN`], *all* the values series are converted to `float`.

Below are minimal examples.

**Conversion to float triggered**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4]})

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns=['B'], values='C', aggfunc='mean')

print(df)

B         a    b    c
A                    
1  2.666667  5.0  6.0
2  7.000000  2.0  4.0
```

**Conversion to float not triggered**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5]})

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns=['B'], values='C', aggfunc='mean')

print(df)

B  a  b  c
A         
1  3  5  6
2  7  2  4
```

Comment: Perfect! I added 'aggfunc= 'sum'' and it fixed the issue. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The default aggregation function, used by [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) is `mean`.

Most probably this is causing float values.

Demo:

```
In [49]: df
Out[49]:
   Year                                              Type  Total
0  2006                            A talk or presentation     34
1  2006                            A talk or presentation      1  # <--- NOTE !!!
2  2006      A magazine, newsletter or online publication     33
3  2006  A formal working group, expert panel or dialogue      2
4  2006    Scientific meeting (conference/symposium etc.)     10
5  2006     A press release, press conference or response      6

In [50]: df.pivot_table(index=['Year'], columns = ['Type'],fill_value=0)
Out[50]:
                                                Total                                               \
Type A formal working group, expert panel or dialogue A magazine, newsletter or online publication
Year
2006                                                2                                           33


Type A press release, press conference or response A talk or presentation Scientific meeting (conference/symposium etc.)
Year
2006                                             6                   17.5                                             10
```

Comment: Thank you MaxU! I fixed it by adding 'aggfunc= 'sum', I didnt realise it was doing the mean!!'

Answer (score 1):

adding `fill_value=0` worked for me in a similar problem.

`df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='A', columns=['B'], values='C', fill_value=0)`

`'aggfunc= 'sum'` had no effect on my data.

Comment: Thank you. This is an old post now, but I will take a look :)

Comment: Hahha yes, I checked the date. I was facing the issue right now. I thought I could provide this answer as well which could help others.